# Running python / ruby interactively from within Notepad++ (NppExec console)

Tags: python, notepad++, ruby, nppexec

I've been using the NppExec console in Notepad to run python and ruby scripts using `python script_name.py` or `ruby script_name.rb`, and for the most part this works well: the output gets redirected into the NppExec console, and I don't have to switch out of Notepad++ to test my script.

However, what I would really like to be able to do is to run an interactive session of python or ruby from the NppExec console.  For example, just `python` or just `irb` don't allow **interactively** working in the console.

Anyone had any luck with this?

If this were possible, it would mean being able to exercise functions / methods in a given script from within the console all without having to leave Notepad++.

Comment: You can use `pry` (for Ruby) and add the lines `require 'pry'` and `binding.pry` to your code to open up the interactive console in the current scope.

Comment: @itdoesntwork: seems wrong to say it, but... it doesn't work!  Seriously though, are you sure you have got this to work calling pry from **within the console window in Notepad++ (NppExec)?**  Appreciate the tip on pry -- have just installed the gem, and it does seem better than irb.  But I don't think it gets me what I'm hoping for: running ruby interactively from within Notepad++ itself.  Let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** (Adding -u unbuffered switch for better performance)

Turns out this is possible for Python using the `-i` (inspect) switch and the -u (unbuffered output) switch, despite the fact that [Npp_Exec is not a true console](https://superuser.com/a/470370/153054):

```
    python -u -i $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)
```

This runs the current file in the Npp_Exec console in the Python interpreter and because of `-i` switch jumps straight into interactive mode where you can then continue *from within the NppExec console* to inspect / use any variables or definitions provided by the script.

If you set your Npp_Exec console to follow the current directory using `Notepad++ Menu > Plugins > NppExec > Follow $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY`, the solution is even simpler:

```
    python -u -i $(FILE_NAME)
```

---

(Note: For Ruby this is still an open question, since Ruby and its interactive interpreter `irb` are two separate binaries, and don't seem to have an inspect type switch along with some other oddities when running scripts that have both input and output... )

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like it's possible. From the NppExec documentation, I quote:

> NppExec is NOT...
>
> - NppExec is not a console emulator. NppExec redirects the running process'es output to its Console window, and can redirect the Console
>     window's input to the running process (with some limitations). The
>     NppExec's Console is not a "real" console window (actually, it uses
>     RichEdit control for text input/output), it does not provide a console
>     screen buffer. Thus, a console application which requires a "real"
>     console screen buffer must be run in its own console window (using
>     NPP_RUN command).
> - NppExec is not a command interpreter. NppExec does not understand such commands as 'copy', 'call', 'for' and so on because it is neither
>     a "real" console nor a console emulator. However, NppExec has its own
>     internal implementation of such commands as 'cls', 'cd', 'dir',
>     'echo', 'set' ('env_set') and introduces other, specific, commands.
>     Also you can use "cmd /c " to execute any cmd's command
>     inside NppExec.
> - NppExec is not a compiler. NppExec allows you to use external tools and compilers to process/compile your current file, but it has no
>     ability to do it by itself. No magic here :)

Since there is no console screen buffer, the NppExec console cannot qualify as a "real" console.

You're much better off trying an application that was designed for interactive testing of code, such as [IPython](http://ipython.org/) for Python.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Your quote about console buffers, NppExec and Npp_run got me looking into this again and testing what exactly NppExec's console buffers do with respect to i/o.  Apparently, they do take both input and reflect output.  So the simple python program `print("Enter anything: ", end=""); response=input(); print(response)` will work when called from within Npp_Exec's console using `python $(FILE_NAME)`.  This has led me to a solution that works -- see answer.  So (+1) for partial response that motivated finding an actual solution!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to python and tried to learn python programming and because of
some issues in IDLE(like line-numbering) I decided to use Notepad++ and
of course **NPP_EXEC** plugin to ease code compiling. I had succeeded in some
others like compiling ***.vbs** files but this time for python it was not
triumph for some reason despite all the solution presented here and else
where.

I tried first the `python -u "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` in NPP_EXEC. For some
python scripts the result was satisfactory and as I proceeded in learning
more in python I encountered a problem again because the output was not as
I expected. I ran into the solution here by [AKE]. unfortunately none of
these worked out to me up to now.

suppose the following code.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
my_dict = dict({'Alice':1, 'John':2, 'Emma':3})
name = raw_input("enter the name: ")
name = name.capitalize()

if name in my_dict:
    #do something here
else: print("The name does not exist!")
#-------------------------------------------------
```

I used both:

```
python -u "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

and

```
python -u -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

but the result's always the same, whatever you enter as name in the above code
the output is always:
  *[The name does not exist!]*
I believe it's because of the `-u` switch, so I tried to omit it and use just `-i` as

```
python -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

It turned out to work but this time after you observed the output you have to
press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate the process manually and exit python **interactive** mode in NPP_EXEC console.

I know of some other work-arounds like using Notepad++ **Run** menu and adding
some commands there or even using **PyNPP** plugin (although these two do almost
identical procedure by redirecting python on cmd), but none of these had the
convenience as I liked. Maybe I Expect too much of NPP_EXEC, because as it
has in its help it's not a real console, but I wanted to do it all in
Notepad++ without dealing with some other processes like IDLE or cmd or ....

Despite this I would appreciate any help if someone had any other successful
experience.